# how can I cast a long in double in VBA

Tags: vba

How can I cast a long to double in VBA ? I have googled here and there, and saw some ugly things such as

```
dim i as long
i = 100
dim d as double
d = i * 1.00000000001
```

I haven't tested this, I guess this is working, but my application is really data sensitive and I'd like to actually have a cast with no effect on data... Does that not exist ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to "cast" anything, this will work fine

```
dim i as long
dim d as double
i = 100
d = i
```

(and it took me about 30 seconds to start Excel, press ALT-F11, and test it).

Answer (score 5):

VBA has a bunch of functions that start with 'C' that are used to explicitly cast between types.  See CLng, CDbl, CDate, to name a few.